# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'. How can i fix this error

Tags: python-3.x

My code is:

```
  'scores = []

   table = open("C:/Users/tungn/Desktop/High.txt")

       for line in table:

      (name,scores)=line.split()

      scores.append(float(scores))

  table.close()

  print(scores[0])

  print(scores[1])'
```

When i run its from IDLE Python appears:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tungn\Desktop\Programing\Head first program\loop_highestscore.py", line 5, in 
    scores.append(float(scores))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

> > > How can i fix this errors? Plzz

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name `scores` in the `line.split()` and for the `list` name. Kindly give a different name in the return statement of `line.split` something like

```
(name,values)=line.split()

scores.append(float(values))
```

That would fix the error. `split` function returns strings and string don't have the attribute `append` that's why you got the error.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Oh.  I get it now/ That's clear, thank you so  much! ^^

Comment: @NguyễnTùng Happy to help you. If you find the answer useful kindly mark the answer as correct for the benefit of others as well. Thanks